# How to take the FFT in a limited range of frequencies?

Tags: matlab, fft

When using the `fft` function in Matlab to take the Fourier transform, one can specify the number of FFT points, `nfft`, and the command is written `fft(x,nfft)`. In this case, what is the frequency vector?

How can the Fourier transform be calculated with the same `nfft`, but over a narrower range of frequencies? How would the frequency vector be calculated?

Comment: Check out the Chirp-Z-transform. You can find some information about it in [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15245/use-chirp-z-transform-for-spectral-resolution/15246#15246).

Answer (score 1):

If your sampling frequency is $f_s$, and you calculate the FFT with $N$ samples, then the FFT calculates the signal's spectrum at $N$ frequencies from $-f_s/2$ to $f_s/2-f_s/N$, inclusive. In Matlab notation, this would be written as:

```
freq_vector = (-N/2:N/2-1)./(f_s/N);
```

(Note that you have to shift the spectrum returned by the FFT operation to correspond to this vector; in Matlab, you would use `fftshift`.)

I don't know of any FFT algorithm that lets you restrict the frequency range. I would suggest using [Goertzel's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) to find the spectrum at the particular frequencies you're interested in. You may also use a bandpass filter to eliminate the unwanted frequencies before performing the FFT.